# .htaccess redirect blog posts but not blog subfolders

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect my old blog folder to my new blog folder but keep post-titles the name.

`/oldblog/post-title` to `/newblog/post-title`

I wrote:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /oldblog/(.*) /newblog/$1
```

This works until I bump into a url like `/oldblog/events/`

I want to exclude `/oldblog/events/` from this rule. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To exclude the oldblog/events , you can use :

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/oldblog/((?!events).*)$ /newblog/$1
```

**Clear your browser's cache before testing this code.**